# How in install all debian files in a folder except older versions

Tags: software-installation, debian-installer

In a folder there are debian files for different packages which were originally downloaded by `sudo apt-get`. I want to install all of then in another Ubuntu system.

The problem is that there may be both newer and older version of the same package in the folder. How can I install all packages in the folder except those for which there is a newer version in it
?

Answer (score 0):

if you install all of them with "sudo dpkg -i *.deb" while inside the folder, it will install all of them, and the newer versions will always "prevail" over the older ones. You will not get double installs, the newer ones will simply update the older ones.